# How to slide right between two HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, css-transitions

Im having trouble with transitioning between two html pages. When the enter button is pressed you will be brought to another page, When this button is pressed the page should simply slide in from the right. http://jsfiddle.net/fs488b3r/5/ in this fiddle is a perfect example of what Im looking for.

Ive tried this code with my own code however it doesn't seem to be working the way it should. Anyone know how I can fix this? or properly implement this? Below is my code, Any help would be much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Landing Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style type="text/css">

@font-face {
font-family: Geoma Regular Demo;
src: url(Geoma Regular Demo.otf);
}


@font-face {
font-family: Geoma Demo;
src: url(Geoma Light demo.otf);
}





@media screen and (max-width: 425px){

html,body{
overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}


#logo {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;}


h1 {color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: Geoma Regular Demo;
font-size: 28px;
margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 25px;}

p{text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Geoma Demo;
margin: 0 ;
padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#enter {margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
font-family: Geoma Demo;
border: 2px solid white;
background-color:#0BF446 ;
border-radius: 0 15px 0 15px;
padding: 10px 30px;}

#enter:hover {background-color:#04A12B;}

.green {margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #0BF446;
border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
padding: 40px 30px 30px 30px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
top: 150px;
}



}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<img src="biglogo.png" id ="logo">

<div class = "green">
<h1>Welcome to Elemental!</h1>

<p>Elemental is an interactive platform,
that allows creative people to discover and
explore design elements inspired by nature
throughout the world</p>


<a href="homepage.html"><button id = "enter">Enter</button></a>



</div>

<script>

function transitionPage() {
    // Hide to left / show from left
    $("#enter").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);

    // Show from right / hide to right
    $("#about-2").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#enter').click(transitionPage);
    $('#about-2').click(transitionPage);
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What this js fiddle essentially does is shift the view within the same page, not load a new page.the jsfiddle has 2 divs (containers of content) which are actually on the same page. Your button

```
<a href="homepage.html"><button id = "enter">Enter</button></a>
```

is a button link to the new page. basically this opens the link before the javascript is run. for the javascript to be run on the same page, your first step, would be to remove the a href

```
<button id = "enter">Enter</button>
```

now this would run the code without loading the new page.

here is something close to what you want to do from my understanding 

-  [the "landing page"](https://aaronlilly.github.io/Example/landingpage.html) 
 or  [view the github repo](https://github.com/aaronlilly/Example)

this code only works for me within the jsfiddle, below is just the javascript portion.

```
function transitionPage() {
// Hide to left / show from left
$("#about-1").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);

window.open("homepage.html","_self");


// Show from right / hide to right
$("#about-2").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#about-1').click(transitionPage);
$('#about-2').click(transitionPage);
});
```

this would be everything in one page (except jquery which is linked) , also fix your css to match the exacts of your page. below would be your landingpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Landing Page</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="Scripts/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
html, body {
font: normal normal 16px Arial;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

p {
font-size: 20px;
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}

.nodisplay {
display: none;
}

#about {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.page {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#logo {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
margin-top: 50px;}


#about-1 {
background-color: #003366;
color: #FFFFFF;
display:inline-block;
}

#about-2 {
background-color: #F6BC0C;
color: #000000;
float:left;
}
</style>

<script>
function transitionPage() {
// Hide to left / show from left
$("#about-1").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);

window.open("homepage.html","_self");


// Show from right / hide to right
$("#about-2").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#about-1').click(transitionPage);
$('#about-2').click(transitionPage);
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
<img src="biglogo.png" id ="logo">

<div id="about">
<div id="about-1" class="page">
    <p>Welcome to Elemental!
Elemental is an interactive platform, that allows creative people to 
discover and explore design elements inspired by nature throughout the 
world</p>
<br>
<button id = "enter" style="color:#000">Enter</button>
</div>
<div id="about-2" class="page nodisplay">
    <p>Content for about 2</p>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

then you just need your second page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Page 2
</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>

html, body {
font: normal normal 16px Arial;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #F6BC0C;
}

#about-2 {
background-color: #F6BC0C;
color: #000000;
float:left;
}

.page {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
p {
font-size: 20px;
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="about-2" class="page nodisplay">
    <p>Content for about 2</p>
</div>
</body>
```